# Can I get Italian visa as quickly as possible if applying from UK?

Tags: schengen-visas, vfs-global

I need to present a study at a conference in Italy on 21st September. That's 60 days from now. I am Pakistani citizen and currently working in UK. I have valid UK residence permit. What is the quickest way to get the Italian visa?

Comment: By applying as soon as possible.

Comment: Have you looked at the application website? https://visa.vfsglobal.com/gbr/en/ita